# Loop for printing CSS style in multiple printed a hrefs

Tags: php, css, loops, hyperlink

I have used the search feature on this site and Googled around but have not found a definitive answer.Hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

I am styling links in a PHP print statement as follows:

```
print '<a href="'.$linkPath.'index.php" style="color:white">Home</a> | <a href="'.$linkPath.'scripts/login.php" style="color:white">Login</a>'. PHP_EOL;
```

This is working for me, however the supplied code is only a brief example and I have several more links.

Considering the fact that this falls into the code redundancy category with the repeating of

```
style="color:white"
```

I am looking for another solution.

Could a loop be used in this situation and if so could someone give an example of how I might write it?

How can I add a style to my links without having to explicitly specify it for every link?

Comment: You mean like defining a `class` and using that instead of `style`?

Comment: well yes i think - should i keep this job for css> I currently have the code wrapped in a <div> but it only styles the background from what i have tried

Comment: @scrblnrd3 please advise if i have not supplied the correct information

Comment: @tokenloko welcome to the site! we generally keep meta-discussion (such as questions about why you've been put on hold) to the meta-site (please go here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and ask for details about why your question was closed). That way, if anyone else is reading the question/answer, they won't have to also read meta-commentary.

Comment: Thanks for that @blueberryfields - so how should I post there just to be sure? I'm not trying to be cheeky but do I copy my whole question from above and then make the same comments as above when posted at meta? Like I said - I'm not overly concerned about re-opening as I have found my solution but for future reference.....

Comment: Leave your original question here, and remove your questions about closing. Open a new question there, with your comments/requests about closing, and add a link to here, from there.

Comment: Much appeciated @blueberryfields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use inline styles. Use CSS classes instead, like this

`print '<a href="'.$linkPath.'index.php" class="white">Home</a> | <a                   href="'.$linkPath.'scripts/login.php" class="white">Login</a>'. PHP_EOL;`

and in your CSS

```
.white{
     color:white;
 }
```

If you truly want to avoid any code redundancy, you can use CSS pseudoselectors

```
#div>a{
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: That'll print number of links with text `Home`, that is probably not what op is looking for :D

Comment: is it possible to loop over each a href="'.$linkPath.  - srry guys - fairly new to all this

Comment: what do i need to supply?

Comment: Wherever you currently have your link paths

Comment: put it in the question

Comment: @scrblnrd: used <div id="examplename"> links </div> along with CSS  #examplename>a{
color: white;
}

Comment: thx to all who responded - pseudo selectors was the answer i was looking for in this case

Answer (score 2):

Probably, using css classes is what you are looking for. You can achieve that using `class` attribute in your tags, of course you have to write those class parameters using css.
CSS:

```
.white {
   color:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="index.php" class="white">Home</a>
```

Well you said something about loops, huh? If you want to power a navigation menu by loops, the best way would be using multidimensional arrays and `for` loop.

```
$links = array('Home' => 'index.php', 'login' => 'login.php');
$values = array_values($links);
$keys = array_keys($links);

for($i=0; $i<count($links); $i++) {
   print('<a href="' . $values[$i] . '" class="white">' . $keys[$i] . '</a> | ');
}
```

`foreach` example(a lot easier though):

```
$links = array('Home' => 'index.php', 'login' => 'login.php');

foreach($links as $val => $link) {
   print('<a href="' . $link . '" class="white">' . $val . '</a> | ');
}
```

Comment: is that still within the bounds of code redundancy though as in that scenario I will be adding class="white" to every a href

Comment: It's better to use classes than inline style, you know it's better to sort every code to its own place, and not to use inline magics.